# Apple pencil click on button or anchor element not working on webapplication

Tags: html, jquery, apple-pencil

We have a webapplication, which works fine when using the finger to touch for actions. We just got a apple pencil but that does not click the buttons or links, we can write using that in the textarea's, but any button click does not work. I tried to search for a probable solution, but could not figure our any directions. Any idea of what could be causing that will be very helpful.

One thing I was able to figure out, if I add the event onmousedown rather than onclick, all the events work, but I do not want to change the whole website code from onclick to onmousedown if there is another easier way of doing this. Thank you for any input !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a proper solution for this. But I have tried this and this seems like working find

```
$(window).bind('touchstart', function(e) {
       e.target.click();
});
```